# How to flag users for mod attention (for editing vandals)

Tags: discussion, support

Over the last days, I had a few attempts of vandalizing questions/answers in my "approve edit" queue. This morning, it was the user "gnu" for three times and I wonder what to do about this. Just rejecting the edit helps the immediate problem of course, but I feel this shouldn't be all.

Edit: 
With Iain's help I got them back, so here are a few examples:

- https://serverfault.com/suggested-edits/1463
- https://serverfault.com/suggested-edits/1464
- https://serverfault.com/suggested-edits/1465

Comment: The only activity shown for that guy is on his own questions: http://serverfault.com/users/63725/gnu?tab=activity  And it looks like he has trouble with english and with doing some work on his own before asking badly formed questions here.

Comment: Since I rejected his edits, they won't show up there.

Comment: They are in http://serverfault.com/tools/suggested-edits

Comment: @Iain: Thanks, I'll edit my question with an example.

Comment: Nice of Splattne to write to the dude but given his 1 rep I'd have been inclined to nuke.

Comment: @Chopper3 It's the SF good cop/bad cop technique. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The edit

> sdfsfsdfsfsfsfsfsffsdfsfs df sf sf s f asf s fs df asf

convinced me that these edits were pretty intentional. So, in this case the user will be suspended for at least one day. Also, he'll receive a warning email.

If there are similar cases, please just flag them and add a short explanation. Moderators will take care of them.

*Thank you!*

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure what to flag to make work the easiest for mods. I couldn't find an option to flag a user or an edit, so do I flag the question or answer that is vandalized?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that if you get enough edit suggestion rejections, you cannot suggest edits for 7 days.

This is enforced both by account and by IP address.